# CSS - Selected link does not maintain colour

Tags: html, css

I have an `<a href>` link as such:

```
<table class='hello'>
    <tr>
        <td><a href = 'javascript:void(0);' onClick=window.open('helloworld.php')></a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The CSS I have tried (which did not work):

```
.hello tr td a.selected {
    color: #F2F2F2;
}
```

and

```
.hello tr td a:visited {
    color: #F2F2F2;
}
```

I know the hierarchy: `.hello tr td a.` is correct as the following works:

```
.hello tr td a:hover {
    color: #F2F2F2;
}
```

When I select the link, a pop-up window opens up, however, I would like the link on the original page to be highlighted (so if the user goes back to the original page, he/she will know what was selected).

However, I can only get the `:active` and `:hover` to work.

`.selected` or `:visited` do not work for some reason.

Comment: What's the point of having an anchor tag (aka a hyperlink) use javascript to open a new page? y u no `<a href="helloworld.php">derp</a>`?

Comment: Why do you think `.selected` _should_ work? The link does not have that class, and you are not adding it dynamically either.

Comment: `.selected` is a class, why you think would work if you are not doing anything with it (adding dynamically like CBroe said for example)? And `:visited` from what I remember, works with what is on the a's `href`, which in your case isn't a page/valid url, therefore it will never be `:visited`.

Comment: My guess is that since it is a pop-up, your browser isn't actually visiting the page so it does not appear in the browser history. I think you will have to use javascript in this case. Once it's clicked, then change the color.

Comment: Take a look at this link: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp. Also when you're using javascript inside the onClick event you need to wrap it in quotation marks like this: `onClick="window.open('url');"`

Comment: Now I understand why .selected would not work, But i still do not understand why :visited would not work. It is still using an `<a href>` link and also shows up in the browser history. Is it possible to do this by avoiding JS altogether?

Comment: a.selected is for <a> with selected class you've not added selected class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't with your CSS. It's the `href` target. If you put `href='javascript:...'` the hyperlink will never be considered visited hence the color will never change.

Change your `<a>` tag to:

```
<a href='helloworld.php'>Hello world</a>
```

The `onclick` handler is unnecessary.

**Edit:**
The OP clarified that the target must be opened as a popup, with parameters, and don't use form.

To make it a popup, add `target='_blank'`. Modify your `href` as needed to pass the parameters you want.

```
<a href='helloworld.php?param1=goodbye&param2=world' target='_blank'>Hello world</a>
```

Comment: The issue is that it has to be a pop up window and I need to send data from the parent window to the popup window. I am trying not to use forms for this method.

Comment: If you have something important to add, please edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

Using `href = 'javascript:void(0);'` is causing your issues.

The `:visited` selector relies on the `href` attribute to tell if the link has been visited.
Also, `.selected` is a class so unless you add it to the link after is it clicked, it will not apply.

See this [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/7j48v/7/)

Additionally, the order of the styles in your CSS matters:

```
a:visited { ... }
a:hover { ... }   // if active is not after hover, the hover style
a:active { ... }  // will override the active style during mousedown
```

Reference: [css-tricks](http://css-tricks.com/when-and-when-not-to-use-an-anchor-tag/)

Comment: Shouldn't the a:visited attribute change the colour of the link to green once I have clicked it?

Comment: Sorry, I was missing the `target="_blank"` in the link in the demo (it wont work correctly in the jsfiddle iframe without it). I updated the link above

Comment: Interestingly enough, in IE the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/7j48v/7/) does change the first link to green (`:visited`) but the behavior doesn't persist between page-loads like it does for the second link (with the `href`). In Chrome, the first link never turns green (expected behavior) and the second link functions as it should (green if the link is in the browser history)... gotta love browser quirks!